If $\{x_n\}$ converges to a non zero positive number then show that $\{nx_n\}$ diverges to $\infty$
Although a proof of this claim is provided here my question is whether I can prove this result this as follows?
My proof
$$
\text{A sequence, $\{a_n\}$, is said to diverge to $\infty$ if for any given $G>0$, however large,}\\
\text{we can find a number $m$, such that,}\\
a_n>G \quad \forall n\ge m \\
$$
$$
\text{Now, since we are given that $\{x_n$\} converges (to $a$ suppose) we can say that,}\\
\forall \epsilon > 0\quad \exists\: N \in \mathbb{N}\quad \text{such that}\quad a-\epsilon<x_n<a+\epsilon\quad \forall n\ge N\\
$$
$$
\Rightarrow x_n < a+\epsilon \quad \forall n\ge N \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x_n} > \frac{1}{a+\epsilon} \quad \forall n\ge N \\ 
$$
\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow \frac{G}{x_n} > \frac{G}{a+\epsilon} \quad \forall n\ge N \,\text{and}\,\text{an arbitrary G > 0} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
$$
\text{Now, let us consider the sequence $\{nx_n\}$.}\\
\text{Now for an arbitrary G>0,}\\
nx_n>G\: \text{if}\: n>\frac{G}{x_n}>\frac{G}{a+\epsilon}\quad \text{from equation (1)}\\
\Rightarrow \text{for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and $G>0$,}\quad nx_n > G \: \forall n > \left(\frac{G}{a+\epsilon}\right)\\
\Rightarrow \{nx_n\} \: \text{diverges to +$\infty$}\\
\textbf{Q.E.D.}
$$
Thank you.

How did you go from $x_n<a+\varepsilon$ to $\frac1{x_n}>\frac1{a+\varepsilon}$?

@Surb It is not being assumed that each $x_n$ is greater than $0$. Only that the limit of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is greater than $0$, from which we can only deduce that $x_n>0$ if $n\gg1$. But the OP fails to mention this.

@JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for your reply! I do see how this makes a hole in my argument. That being said, if i had mentioned the point that you pointed out, would that make my proof correct?

Yes, it is correct

I didn't check your proof into details, but I don't get why you introduced $\frac{1}{x_n}$. Things are much easier :

Let $a>0$ be the limits of $(x_n)$. Fix $G>0$. Take $\varepsilon >0$ small enough s.t. $a-\varepsilon >0$, and $N\in \mathbb N$ big enough s.t. $$x_n>a-\varepsilon \quad \text{and}\quad n(a-\varepsilon )>G,$$ for all $n>N$. Therefore, if $n>N$ then $$nx_n>n(a-\varepsilon )>G,$$
what prove the claim.

It might be even simpler to explicitly choose $\varepsilon=a/2$. But I suppose that is a question of taste.

I think your proof is basically correct!
I offer I think another way to look at it by passing through subsequences. But it turned more complicated than I thought.
Since $x_n \to a > 0$ as $n\to\infty$, as you mentioned there is some index $m$ from which the sequence is positive and stays near $a$ within some tolerance $0<\epsilon<\min(a,1)$,
$$x_n \in (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) \subset (0,a+\epsilon)$$
for all $n\geq m$. So let's prove the result on this subsequence, denoted $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty = \{x_n\}_{n=m}^\infty$. If this new series diverges after scaling by $n$, then so does the original.
Well we know for any such $\epsilon$, there is some multiple $N_1(a-\epsilon)$ of $a-\epsilon$ that exceeds $2a$, so that
$$ n y_n > 2a \,\,\forall n\geq N_1 . $$
Similarly, there is $N_2$ such that $ n y_n > 3a \,\,\forall n\geq N_2 $.
Generally, we found a sequence $\{ N_1,N_2,\dots \}$ of indices such that $N_k y_{N_k} > (k-1)a$ for all $k$. Since $\{(k-1)a\}_{k=1}^\infty$ diverges as $k\to\infty$, so does $\{k y_k\}_{k=N_1,N_2,\dots}$ by comparison. Therefore so does the parent sequence $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, and so does the original $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$

This is indeed a very different way of thinking about this...although I dont 100% understand your proof yet (i guess i'll need to go over it a few times...This is my first course in Real Analysis).Thanks for your reply.
